# What does "This RSS feed URL is deprecated" mean in chat?

Tags: support

I had the Observatory chat window open and when I looked at it I saw four copies of the message

> [This RSS feed URL is deprecated](https://news.google.com/news)

What does this mean? The link in the messages is just `https://news.google.com/news`.

> [image: screen shot Observatory chat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a Google News feed for Astronomy set up, but it appears to be no longer functional. I'm removing the feed now.